How to disable selection highlighting on iTerm2?
Every time I click something on the terminal, it highlights that line or block or whatever. How do I disable this? If you look at the screenshot below, I clicked on the bottom part of the terminal and it "highlights" that entire portion.
Edit
Turns out the problem had nothing to do with Zsh; it was one of iTerm2's recent updates that was causing the problem.


Which terminal emulator are you using?

@mpy I'm currently using iTerm2.

Although you commented on the (now deleted) answer, that this does not happen with bash, it really sounds like an terminal emulator thing. Try to use a simple prompt like PS1='%~> ' and check if the behavior changes.

Setting PS1 as that changed what the shell prompt looks like but didn't do anything about the highlighting problem. I think that you're right; it seems like iTerm2 had some changes or updates recently so I might be looking in the wrong place.

I faced the same issue. After looking at the changelogs, I noticed that with version 3.5.0, a lot of features were introduced. One such feature is:
  You can click a command to select it. Search,
  Filter, and Select All will then be restricted
  to the selected command. You can disable this
  feature in Settings > General > Selection.

So to turn off the highlight, click go to Settings > General > Selection and remove the tick from Clicking on the command selects it to restrict Find and Filter


This block selection stuff in iterm2 was driving me nuts and I thought I'd been over all settings multiple times in order to disable it. That said, I always spend way too much time figuring out where an iterm2 setting is located. Thanks so much for the pointer!

I feel like that setting should be disabled by default.

Me too. This also drove me nuts!!! Thanks.
